How Can I Bypass the Btrfs Check When Using Leapp to Upgrade from CentOS 7 to Oracle Linux with UEK Kernel?
I'm attempting to upgrade a CentOS 7 system to Oracle Linux using the Leapp upgrade tool. My system uses Btrfs, and Leapp inhibits the upgrade because of this. However, the UEK kernel from Oracle Linux supports Btrfs. How can I bypass the Btrfs check in Leapp to proceed with the upgrade? Any guidance or alternative methods would be appreciated. Thank you!

If no one has an idea to solve my issue, I will use centos2ol instead: https://github.com/oracle/centos2ol

Are you using btrfs as your root filesystem, or just as a data filesystem?
If there are no parts of the operating system on the btrfs filesystem, just comment out the /etc/fstab entry/entries for it, and boot the system without the btrfs filesystem before starting the upgrade.
After the upgrade is complete, uncomment the /etc/fstab line(s) you commented out, and then mount your btrfs.

I am using btrfs as root file system. But thanks for the idea.
